# RxSwift How to split progress and result observables?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-swift

I need to make a long async calculation based on a `String` input and return a big `Data` instance.
I use `Single` trait to achieve this:

```
func calculateData(from: String) -> Single<Data>
```

This example is simple and works. But I also need to track progress — a number between 0 and 1. I'm doing something like this:

```
func calculateData(from: String) -> Observable<(Float, Data?)>
```

where I get the following sequence:

```
next: (0, nil)
next: (0.25, nil)
next: (0.5, nil)
next: (0.75, nil)
next: (1, result data)
complete
```

I check for progress and data to understand if I have a result, it works, but I feel some strong smell here. I want to separate streams: `Observable` with progress and `Single` with a result. I know I can return a tuple or structure with two observables, but I don't like this as well.

How can I achieve this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is fine although I would name the elements in the tuple

```
func calculateData(from: String) -> Observable<(percent: Float, data: Data?)>

let result = calculateData(from: myString)
    .share()

result
    .map { $0.percent }
    .subscribe(onNext: { print("percent complete:", $0) }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

result
    .compactMap { $0.data }
    .subscribe(onNext: { print("completed data:", $0) }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Another option is to use an enum that either returns percent complete OR the data:

```
enum Progress {
    case incomplete(Float)
    case complete(Data)
}

func calculateData(from: String) -> Observable<Progress>
```

However, doing that would make it harder to break the Observable up into two streams. To do so, you would have to extend Progress like so:

```
extension Progress {
    var percent: Float {
        switch self {
        case .incomplete(let percent):
            return percent
        case .complete:
            return 1
        }
    }

    var data: Data? {
        switch self {
        case .incomplete:
            return nil
        case .complete(let data):
            return data
        }
    }
}
```

And as you see, doing the above essentially turns the enum into the tuple you are already using. The nice thing about this though is that you get a compile time guarantee that if Data emits, the progress will be 1.

If you want the best of both worlds, then use a struct:

```
struct Progress {
    let percent: Float
    let data: Data?

    init(percent: Float) {
        guard 0 <= percent && percent < 1 else { fatalError() }
        self.percent = percent
        self.data = nil
    }

    init(data: Data) {
        self.percent = 1
        self.data = data
    }
}

func calculateData(from: String) -> Observable<Progress>
```

The above provides the compile time guarantee of the enum and the ease of splitting that you get with the tuple. It also provides a run-time guarantee that progress will be 0...1 and if it's 1, then data will exist.

Comment: Perfect! I already turned to a struct and I think it's the right thing.